# starting mercurial hg web server from windows command line

Tags: windows, mercurial

Anybody knows how I can start hgweb (mercurial hg web server) from the windows command line?

Currently to run it I am doing a rightclick on the explorer window in a repository folder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
D:\>hg serve
listening at http://my.host.name:8888/ (bound to *:8888)
```

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to kill it.

Answer (score 1):

You can start q web server using *'hg serve'* and that will listen on the default port: 8000.
Or you can specify a port *'hg serve -p XXXX'*

I use it on a batch file and start it automatically.